# spectroscopy: \#{} without non-breaking space

Tags: chemmacros

When using `\#{}` in the `experimental` environment of `chemmacros` it gives the number followed by the nucleus, but they are separated by a regular space, instead of a non-breaking space.

I don't know if this is intentional, but it can lead to the nucleus being printed in the next line, whereas it should be treated as a unit and therefore stick to the number.

Is there a way to redefine this macro by myself or will I have to manually type `2~H` for now?

My MWE:

```
\documentclass{scrbook} 

\usepackage{chemmacros}
\chemsetup{modules={spectroscopy}}

\begin{document}
    \begin{experimental}
        \NMR(300)[CD3COOD]
            \val{9.87} (d, \J{1.2}, \#{1}),
            \val{6.54} (d, \J{3.4}, \#{2}).
    \end{experimental}
\end{document}
```

giving me (notice the H in the second line).

[image]

Comment: the question would be much easier to answer if there was a MWE

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`\#` is defined in the `spectroscopy` module (the file `chemmacros.module.spectroscopy.code.tex`) to be equal to `\chemmacros_nmr_number:n` inside the `experimental` environment. This function is defined as

```
\cs_new_protected:Npn \chemmacros_nmr_number:n #1
  {
    \__chemmacros_nmr_number:n {#1}
    \skip_horizontal:N \l__chemmacros_nmr_space_skip
    \chemmacros_chemformula:V \g__chemmacros_nmr_element_tl
  }
```

but probably should be defined like this:

```
\cs_new_protected:Npn \chemmacros_nmr_number:n #1
  {
    \__chemmacros_nmr_number:n {#1}
    \chemmacros_skip_nobreak:N \l__chemmacros_nmr_space_skip
    \chemmacros_chemformula:V \g__chemmacros_nmr_element_tl
  }
```

So you can add this to your preamble:

```
\ExplSyntaxOn
\cs_set_protected:Npn \chemmacros_nmr_number:n #1
  {
    \__chemmacros_nmr_number:n {#1}
    \chemmacros_skip_nobreak:N \l__chemmacros_nmr_space_skip
    \chemmacros_chemformula:V \g__chemmacros_nmr_element_tl
  }
\ExplSyntaxOff
```

*after* loading the `spectroscopy` module.

I'll change this in the package. The fix will be included starting with v5.8c.

Comment: Perfect! I was actually just looking at that same snippet of code on GitHub trying to find an answer before posting my question, but I couldn't make any sense of it. :)